# How to Access Input tag on server side

Tags: asp.net, input, aspxgridview

I want to Access Input tag on server side. As I understand

```
<input id="txtText1" type="text" placeholder="monkey" runat="server" />
```

in CS

```
String s = txtText1.value;
```

But In my case Input fields are inside ASPxGridView So i tried bellow attempts :

```
string CustomerCode = ((HtmlInputControl)row.FindControl("CustomerCode")).Value;
            string CustomerCode = row.Cells[0].Text;
            string CustomerCode = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("CustomerCode")).Text;
```

But no Success

Since I want to access This field on _RowInserting Event.

```
 <DetailRow>
    <dx:ASPxGridView ID="dgCustomers" runat="server" KeyFieldName="CustomerCode"
  OnBeforePerformDataSelect="dgCustomers_BeforePerformDataSelect"OnDataBinding="dgCustomers_DataBinding"
                    Width="100%" OnRowDeleting="dgCustomers_RowDeleting" OnRowInserting="dgCustomers_RowInserting"
                    OnRowUpdating="dgCustomers_RowUpdating">
      <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CustomerCode" VisibleIndex="0">
          <EditItemTemplate>
            <input runat="server" id="txtText1" size="55" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustCode" runat="server" Width="100px" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClientClick="return YourJavaScriptFunction();" />
          </EditItemTemplate>
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

.CS

```
protected void dgCustomers_RowInserting(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataInsertingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = false;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_Insert_Line_Item", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerCode", Input_Value);//Here i need to pass the value
        }
```

Can any one help me on same ?

Comment: Try `(TextBox)row.FindControl("txtText1")` , currently your trying to find based on the column name.

Comment: @JonP I tried Change my code but on row its showing error Like row does not exist in current context